# Linux Mint 20 is booting to Login prompt on command line

Tags: boot, login, command, startx

I upgraded my Linux Mint to Release 20 Ulyana from Release 18. After the upgrade now my Mint boot to login prompt on command line. I can login fine but i have to type `startx` on command line to get to my desktop. I like it to be same as before where i boot to desktop straight. what i'm missing here?. please help.

As per instructions i have installed lightdm services. After reboot and checking status of the lightdm service i get the following status. Looks like something is missing.

```
    systemctl status lightdm
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-11-27 20:10:21 PST; 1min 47s ago
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
    Process: 965 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 975 (lightdm)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 4576)
     Memory: 97.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
             ├─ 975 /usr/sbin/lightdm
             └─1008 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch

Nov 27 20:10:23 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1213]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Nov 27 20:10:25 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 27 20:10:25 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Nov 27 20:10:25 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 27 20:10:25 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Nov 27 20:10:25 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "smaqsood"
Nov 27 20:10:36 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Nov 27 20:10:36 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Nov 27 20:10:36 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user smaqsood by (uid=0)
Nov 27 20:10:36 smaqsood-LinuxMint lightdm[1364]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
```

Comment: This should be a simple issue. system works OK. All i have to do is login on command line and run startX to get to my desktop environment. I have looked at my startup application settings for both Cinnamon-settings and Gnome-session- properties and they both list StartX in there.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your DM isn't enabled, I believe Linux Mint 20 uses LightDM, so try `systemctl enable lightdm` and reboot.

Comment: Failed to enable unit: Unit file lightdm.service does not exist. 
I get above error when run suggested command. On reboot i still have to login on command line and run startx to get to my desktop environment.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall a DM, for lightdm I believe it should be `sudo apt install lightdm`

Comment: I have installed the lightdm service as per your instructions. After reboot i get login prompt on GUI (low resolution, small window). After login i get to my desktop. It does solve my original issue of getting to desktop on boot but it looks like a workaround. My experience on previous Mint releases was nice full resolution login GUI screen which i don't have it anymore. I feel like some boot up issue is still there. Anyway i appreciate your time and support. I guess i'll live with this route of booting. Thank you.

Comment: i have updated my question with lightdm status after reboot. there seems to be some errors in red.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but possibly updating your graphics drivers may help.